# How does Asynchronous works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

javascript is single threaded. How does Async works? What i have understood is - Since we are passing by reference, the main thread is not waiting for the response from the called program. But the called program will still be in the call stack and resources assigned to it. Are we using events to send an interrupt to the main function once the work is completed by the called program? But that would require polling some queues in a loop in a timed fashion. Also, when an async (Since async is special kind of call), is the program that is called is moved to web browser's call stack or still stays in my application's call stack?

Comment: More info about event loop [here](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: thanks HMR. Saw the video and there is a message queue as well in addition to stack that helped me understand. May be that also answered another question in my head as to why the examples i have seen for async code have functions calling function. I think that is done to add a single message to the queue whenever the request is complete and then the message is broken down by calls and added to the call stack by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not single-threaded.

It just has an event loop (which is the main entry point to a program) and no built-in mechanisms to spawn new threads.

Functions provided by the host environment *can* span other threads.